# Adding State with Jquery Address once only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

I've seen somewhere on here how to switch the hash for another value, which I've done

```
    $.address.state('s');
```

This gets called once, and works fine.

I then for each page change add the ID

```
    $.address.value( id );
```

Which works fine the first time. The trouble I'm having is the s get's added with each page change, i.e.

1. example.com/s/1
2. example.com/s/s/2

Any ideas how to get example.com/s/2 ?

Comment: please tell where $.address came from

Comment: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Answer (score 0):

This did it

```
$.address.state('/');
// switching off auto update in order to avoid adding value to the browser history
$.address.autoUpdate(false);
$.address.value(document.location.pathname+document.location.search);
$.address.autoUpdate(true);
```